# How to merge datasets with data for each countries but merge only the first available date for that month, for all 6 months?

Tags: r

**I have two datasets:**

**First dataset has, let's say 3 rows, one for each countries:**

| country | population |
| --- | --- |
| Afganistan | 23900 |
| India | 45980 |
| USA | 784560 |

**Second dataset looks like this:**

| country | date | deaths |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afganistan | 02/13/2021 | 134 |
| Afganistan | 02/18/2021 | 342 |
| Afganistan | 02/22/2021 | 543 |
| Afganistan | 03/02/2021 | 421 |
| Afganistan | 03/07/2021 | 456 |
| Afganistan | 03/16/2021 | 675 |
| Afganistan | 03/19/2021 | 689 |
| India | 02/02/2021 | 4889 |
| India | 02/09/2021 | 456 |
| India | 02/16/2021 | 421 |
| India | 03/04/2021 | 98900 |
| India | 03/17/2021 | 83123 |
| India | 03/28/2021 | 7645 |
| USA | 02/05/2021 | 678 |
| USA | 02/13/2021 | 6000 |
| USA | 02/19/2021 | 34500 |
| USA | 02/21/2021 | 13458 |
| USA | 03/05/2021 | 3679 |
| USA | 03/21/2021 | 6591 |
| USA | 03/26/2021 | 1780 |
| USA | 03/29/2021 | 2644 |

Now I need to merge these two files in **R** in such a way that I will have two new columns - one each for Febryary and March deaths, and the value for death column in the final file will be from the first available date for that particular month. The file after merge should look like this:

| country | population | february_death | march_death |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afganistan | 23900 | 134 | 421 |
| India | 45980 | 4889 | 98900 |
| USA | 784560 | 678 | 3679 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
merged <- df2 |>
 transform(date=as.Date(date, '%y/%m/%d')) |>
 with(aggregate(list(deaths=deaths), 
                list(month=strftime(date, '%B'), country=country), 
                \(x) x[1])) |>
 reshape(direction='wide', timevar='month', idvar='code') |>
 merge(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  #Join population data.frame with the count of death by the first date of each country and month
  left_join(
    df2 %>% 
      #Transform column date in an date object
      mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>%
      #Group operations by country and month
      group_by(country,month = month(date,label = TRUE,abbr = FALSE)) %>% 
      #Filter the first date by each country and month
      filter(date == min(date)) %>% 
      #Remove the column date
      select(-date) %>% 
      #Create columns for each first date in each month
      pivot_wider(names_from = month,values_from = deaths,names_prefix = "death_")
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  country    population death_february death_march
  <chr>           <int>           <int>       <int>
1 Afganistan      23900             134         421
2 India           45980            4889       98900
3 USA            784560             678        3679
```

Answer (score 0):

You may join `df1` and `df2` by `Country`, extract the month value from date and reshape the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'country') %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
  arrange(country, date) %>%
  mutate(date = paste0('death_', format(date, '%b'))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = deaths, values_fn = first)

#  country    population death_Feb death_Mar
#  <chr>           <int>     <int>     <int>
#1 Afganistan      23900       134       421
#2 India           45980      4889     98900
#3 USA            784560       678      3679
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("Afganistan", "India", "USA"), population = c(23900L, 
45980L, 784560L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(country = c("Afganistan", "Afganistan", "Afganistan", 
"Afganistan", "Afganistan", "Afganistan", "Afganistan", "India", 
"India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), date = c("02/13/2021", "02/18/2021", 
"02/22/2021", "03/02/2021", "03/07/2021", "03/16/2021", "03/19/2021", 
"02/02/2021", "02/09/2021", "02/16/2021", "03/04/2021", "03/17/2021", 
"03/28/2021", "02/05/2021", "02/13/2021", "02/19/2021", "02/21/2021", 
"03/05/2021", "03/21/2021", "03/26/2021", "03/29/2021"), deaths = c(134L, 
342L, 543L, 421L, 456L, 675L, 689L, 4889L, 456L, 421L, 98900L, 
83123L, 7645L, 678L, 6000L, 34500L, 13458L, 3679L, 6591L, 1780L, 
2644L)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I received this error (I have code instead of country, tot_vacc instead of death.  This the code I used:                                                                                                                                    merged1<- master_allcountry_NewVARoecdandpartner %>%
     left_join(tot_vacc, by = 'code') %>%
     mutate(date = as.Date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>%
     arrange(code, date) %>%
     mutate(date = paste0('totalvacc_', format(date, '%b'))) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = total_vaccinations, values_fn = first)

Comment: This is the error I got: Error in values_fn[[value]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Column `code` has different attributes on LHS and RHS of join 
2: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y'
>

Comment: I have 156 countries in my list, and some counties maynot have data for some months (so there are no rows for some months; is this causing the problem? if yes how to sort this out?

Comment: Please create a small and reproducible example of your actual data. It is difficult to answer question based on the explanation in comments. If you can show an example of what you have and what you want it is easier to answer the question.